# Orientdb. Correct query with index

Tags: indexing, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have question about using index in query in OrientDB.

For example, I have Class X with only one property x. Class X has a lot records, for example 200 000.

Query: `select * from X where x=y`
Execute very long.

I created index on x property.

Query: `select * from X where x=y`
Execute very long.

Query: `select expand(z) from index X.x where x=y`
Execute fast

Which query is correct (when using index):

(1) `select * from X where x=y`

(2) `select expand(z) from index X.x where x=y`

Comment: If you run "explain select * from X where x=y" in the property involvedIndexes do you see your index x.x ?

Comment: Yes, I see index.

Comment: What type of index is it? SBTREE or HASH?

Comment: Can you post the Class properties and indexes so we can try to reproduce it?